# Could we restrict a user from editing a field

Tags: custom-field

Is there a possibility to make user to restrict from editing a field but they should be able to input the data on that field at the time of creating the record.

for example an user should be able to input the Amount data in a field but should not be able to edit once the record is created only ADMIN Access should be able to edit that field

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283072/can-you-restrict-edit-access-to-a-field-after-one-time-edited

Answer (score 0):

You can add the field twice to a lightning record page using field visibility filters based on a custom checkbox field that is updated automatically on record creation.

- Create a checkbox field unchecked by default
- Create automation (flow/trigger) that enables the checkbox after inserting the record.
- Field 1 in LRP: Edit - Flag field visibility filter value = false
- Field 2 in LRP: Read only - Flag field visibility filter value = true

The field visibility filter can also exclude admin users.

Note that the user would still be able to edit the field if present in list views with inline edit mode enabled.